# cocos2d-x 3.8 -how to set up post-processing

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

How do I apply post processing filters to current main layer (like blurring the entire screen etc...)? I figured i should create a new RenderTexture and make the main layer visits it every frame, but now i don't know what to do next.
Is this the right approach?

**SOLVED:** yup I was 50% there, all I was missing was the sprite generated from RenderTexture, just add it to the scene and voila, it's there! *Important:* for this to work you need to restructure your scene a bit, create 2 layers, 1 called mainLayer and the other postProcessingLayer, **they must be siblings**, the mainLayer contains all the sprites, the postProcessingLayer contains the result sprite you just created thru RenderTexture.
Sorry if my explanation is unclear, here's the code:
**PP.cpp**

```
PP::PP(){
    width = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().width;
    height = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height;
    rt = RenderTexture::create(width, height);
    rt->retain();
}
Sprite* PP::getSprite(){
    if (rt){
        auto layer = Sprite::createWithTexture(rt->getSprite()->getTexture());
        layer->setFlipY(true);
        return layer;
    }
}
void PP::draw(Layer* layer){
    rt->begin();
    layer->visit();
    rt->end();
}
```

**GameScene.cpp**

```
bool GameScene::init()
{
    scheduleUpdate();

    mainLayer = Layer::create();
    this->addChild(mainLayer);
    mainLayer->addChild(background);

    postProcessingLayer = Layer::create();
    this->addChild(postProcessingLayer, 1);
    filter= new PP();
    auto reverseRGBSprite = filter->getSprite();
    reverseRGBSprite->setPosition(visibleSize.width / 2, visibleSize.height / 2);
    CustomShader::reverseRGB(reverseRGBSprite);
    postProcessingLayer->addChild(reverseRGBSprite);

    postProcessingLayer2 = Layer::create();
    this->addChild(postProcessingLayer2, 2);
    auto blur = filter->getSprite();
    blur->setPosition(visibleSize.width / 2, visibleSize.height / 2);
    CustomShader::gaussianBlur(blur);
    postProcessingLayer2->addChild(blur);

    return true;
}

void GameScene::update(float delta){
    filter->draw(mainLayer);
    filter->draw(postProcessingLayer);
}
```

CustomShader.cpp

```
GLProgram* CustomShader::init(std::string const &vert,std::string const &frag){
    auto prog = new GLProgram();

    prog->initWithFilenames(vert, frag);
    prog->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_POSITION, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
    prog->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_COLOR, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR);
    prog->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEX_COORD, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORD);
    prog->link();
    prog->updateUniforms();

    return prog;
}

void CustomShader::reverseRGB(Sprite *sprite){
    auto prog = CustomShader::init("shaders/reverseRGB.vert", "shaders/reverseRGB.frag");

    sprite->setShaderProgram(prog);
}
```

Comment: what is CustomShader

Comment: you can make your own shaders for sprite to use, there are plenty tutorials for that: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10862/how-to-create-cool-effects-with-custom-shaders-in-opengl-es-2-0-and-cocos2d-2-x. my 'CustomShader' is just a static class packed with all the codes needed to make it works.

Comment: can you give your CustomShader class